# DataGridView filter rows based on a value

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express

I am working on a windows form in vs2013.I am trying to display records based on a variable on to DataGridView when my form loads. I have tried a whole variety of code based on some google research.

I am connect form data to an access database.

Here is the code:

```
Dim maxrecords As Integer
Dim firstrecord As Integer
Dim currentrecord As Integer
Dim deletedrecordnum As Integer
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim del As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim dbprov As String
Dim dbsource As String
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dsDelete As New DataSet
Dim daDelete As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim sql As String
Dim sqlDelete As String
Dim currentday As String

'This is the first thing that happens before the form loads up on the screen
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dbprov = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    dbsource = "Data Source = C:\VB_Projects\database1.accdb"
    sql = "SELECT * FROM T_Cutdata"
    sqlDelete = "SELECT * FROM T_DeletedData"
    con.ConnectionString = dbprov & dbsource
    con.Open()
    MsgBox("Open")
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "lawncutdata")
    daDelete = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlDelete, con)
    daDelete.Fill(dsDelete, "lawncutdata")
    con.Close()
    MsgBox("Closed")

    If IsDBNull(ds.Tables("lawncutdata").Rows(0).Item(3)) Then
        CheckBox1.Checked = False
    Else
        CheckBox1.Checked = ds.Tables("lawncutdata").Rows(0).Item(3)
    End If

    If IsDBNull(ds.Tables("lawncutdata").Rows(0).Item(5)) Then
        TextBox5.Text = ""
    Else
        TextBox5.Text = ds.Tables("lawncutdata").Rows(0).Item(5)
    End If
    maxrecords = ds.Tables("lawncutdata").Rows.Count - 1
    currentrecord = 0
    firstrecord = 0
    currentday = "Monday"
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("lawncutdata")
    For i As Integer = firstrecord To maxrecords
        If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).ToString = currentday Then
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("lawncutdata").Rows(3)
    EndIf
Next
    ds.Tables("lawncutdata").DefaultView.RowFilter.Contains("Monday")
End Sub
```

PS: What is the best way to store daily data? I will be inputting data on a daily basis. Should I create a table for monday, tuesday, etc?

I am having such a hard time with this. Any help is truly appreciated.

Thanks
melmatvar

Comment: Your question title and actual requirement are completely different. Are you trying to filter records based on given parameter value or want to store data into database. And give some bifurcation about your code?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Filtering records with a given value was my question.At the same time, storing data to a database, i as looking for an opinion.

Comment: then how about **@jmcilhinney 's** suggestion. That will filter the records in your datagridview?

Comment: What is the syntax for the filterString

Comment: have u tried like given suggestion in my post @melmatvar

Comment: i request u to accept jmcilhinney's answer. coz my answer is just a suggestion and already same answer has given by jmcilhinney.

Comment: sorry jmcilhinney, shell. I thought I could pick both and I ended up picking one because they were the same.

Comment: Any thoughts on how I could get it to update the filter so that when another data is added it would display in datagridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of your loop.  Set the `DefaultView.RowFilter` of the `DataTable` and then assign the `DataTable` to the `DataSource` of the grid.  That's it: filter and bind.  To filter, you actually have to assign a `String` to the `RowFilter`, e.g.

```
myDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = filterString
```

That said, if you only want one day's data to display then you should only retrieve one day's data from the database.  If you want to be able to change the filter without requerying then get all the data.

No, you should absolutely not create multiple tables.  Each table represents a single entity.  The entity is not different because it relates to a different day.  One table with a column for the day/date/whatever is the correct option.

Comment: I tried that and nothing shows up. This is what I have so far.
    `Dim dt as New DataTable    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "cutday = 'Monday'"
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt`

Comment: If that's all the code you have then of course nothing shows up because your `DataTable` has no rows or even any columns.  If you actually did populate the `DataTable` and still see no rows in the grid then there are no rows in that `DataTable` with "Monday" in the `cutday` column.  If you need to post more code then please edit your question because, as you can see, comments don't handle code very well.

Comment: I got it to work, but it wont update if i add a new record. I am a newb at this.

Comment: Do you mean update the database?  That's not really relevant to this question.  I'd suggest asking a new question on that topic specifically.

Comment: I figured it out. It was a matter of refreshing the datagridview. Thank you all for the help. I was in between a rock and a hard place. Thank you.

Comment: I never really use the `RowFilter` of a `DataView` because I generally bind via a `BindingSource`.  If you bind your `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the grid, you can then set the `Filter` of the `BindingSource` the same way and the grid should update automatically.